# Google login does not show account picker for devices with single google accounts

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google plus sign in for an android app. I followed the guide on the google developer page "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started". My only problem is that when there's only one google account on the device, the account picker dialog does not show. Is there a way around this?

[image: Google Plus Account Picker]

Comment: If you're using `AccountPicker` explicitly (not part of the "quick start" tutorial for Google+), there is an `alwaysPromptForAccount` argument that changes this behavior. However, please heed @tyczj's comment. Changing the default behavior will make unnecessary work for your users.

Comment: @tyczj, I want the user to be able to choose to add a different account.

Comment: @euniceadu if there is one account how will they choose another?

Comment: @tyczj, so that the user can have the option of choosing the "add account" option(if a user wanted to login with an account either than the one tied to the phone. just like in the google plus app.).

Comment: @tyczj, I have added an image to depict what I'm talking about.

Comment: did you got the solution to this??

Comment: @dcool, no I haven't. I stopped trying to fix it but I will take a hack at it again tomorrow. I will let you know if I find a solution

Comment: thax for update @euniceadu, yea please do update as it is some trick which i am not able to get into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used an AccountPicker as suggested by @acj. I start an AccountPicker intent

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                new String[] { "com.google" }, true, null, null, null,
                null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACCOUNT_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and when the result is returned, I initialize the GoogleApiClient, setting the accountName as stated on the developer page:

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
     .addApi(Plus.API)
     .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
     .setAccountName("users.account.name@gmail.com")
     .build();
client.connect();
```

@dcool, hope this helps.

Comment: the key there is the "true" parameter in newChooseAccountIntent, which means that the picker should always be shown even if there is a single account