# 1 User Multiple Accounts 1 android app transfer data from login activity to splashscreen activity

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, splash-screen

I'm developing an app where user must be able to switch between his accounts. As of now I'm able to allow the app with one account log in. How can I allow the user to create an another account and then switch between them in my android app?

update:-

[I'm able to auth by Google button (firebase)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87JPf.jpg)

[I want to do something like this in my app!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ganLV.jpg)

In my login.class I stored the value of UID which i got from firebase. Now i want to send this data to my splashscreen where it will check if uid==null then it will redirect to login and if uid !=null then it will redirect to MainActivity.

**login.class**

```
 String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
                    String uid = "uidKey";
                    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = login.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("uid", UID);
                    editor.putBoolean("is_logged_before",true); //this line will do trick
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(login.this,"uid:"+UID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String uid1 = sharedpreferences.getString("uid", "");
                    Log.i("shareduser",uid1);

                    Intent i = new Intent(login.this,splashScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("message",uid1);
                    startActivity(i);
```

**splashscreen**

public class splashScreen extends Activity {

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            /*Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String message = bundle.getString("message");
            Log.i("received uid",message);*/

            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(splashScreen.this, login.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();



        }
    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

}
```

}

Comment: provide some of you current implementation steps

Comment: I have updated my query.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your answer is very wide. Please ask only genuine doubts related to programming only.

Looks like you need to implement Auto-Login of the User. For this you need to use Shared Preferences.

After successful login of the user, store the username and password in the shared preferences.

Then when the user again tries to login you need to check the sharedPref to check for the username and password.
Moreover it again depends on the type of authentication you are implementing as you can also get the Session Id for the user.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185260/how-to-auto-login-when-i-run-the-android-application) for that

Also for Account Picker check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184652/google-login-does-not-show-account-picker-for-devices-with-single-google-account)

Comment: I'm able to authenticate the user. I just want 2 accounts in one android app.Instagram allows you to switch between your accounts. I want to do something like that!

Comment: Yes if you want to support multiple accounts you need to remember the username and passwords. This can be achieved by Shared Preferences. On clicking the  add account  menu take the user back to the Login Page and then store the username and password. If the User Logs Out clear data from Shared Preferences